# Air travel in Canada with a medical implant

Tags: health, canada, airport-security

I understand there's some official card I need to go through airport security with metal in my leg.  How do I apply for that?  I don't know where to begin.

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16617/how-to-convince-airport-security-that-i-am-not-dangerous-when-having-metallic-pa

Comment: Follow up:  The day of travel I had so much on my mind I forgot entirely about my implant. I walked through the metal detector with no expectation of an alarm, and there was no alarm.  I guess the metal in my implant is not magnetic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These days security personnel are trained for it, and it's a lot more common.  So common, in fact, that the Canadian government has an entire page on it:

[Travelling with a Medical Device](http://travel.gc.ca/travelling/health-safety/medical-device)

> Check with your doctor before flying to make sure it is safe for you
>   to go through the metal detector at the security checkpoint. Always
>   carry documents that support your medical condition.

Essentially, a simple letter from your doctor/surgeon describing the surgery, the implant, and whether or not you're able to go through the scanners for safety reasons will be adequate.  Ideally have it on his letterhead, just in case they need to call him (although that's unlikely).

Additional source: I have (several) medical implants too and travelled last year in Canada.

Comment: Thanks.  I called CATSA and they told me there was no official card and they don't require a special note.  His advice was to arrive early and that when I arrive I directly approach an agent and tell them the situation.