# Titanium in Body. Should I be careful of anything?

Tags: health, airport-security, x-ray-machines

I have an all titanium wire mesh underneath my eye due to a car accident. It is **supposed to be MRI and X-Ray safe** and I *have* traveled with it once before. I usually avoid informing security beforehand in order to avoid additional security checks and confusions.

Is there something I should be worried about **health-wise** at airports or at security checks wherein it would be a better decision to inform them beforehand rather than running into some medical issues?

Comment: Anything? I'm tempted to say, "Be careful of titanium-scavenging bots from Skynet" but I suspect that's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @jpatokal I'm more worried about the medical issues. I don't want a sudden bleeding in my eye due to some device and then later be told by the airport authority." Oh you never informed us. Not out fault."

Comment: That sounds more like a medical question, rather than a travel one, and I'd highly recommend you ask your medical professional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not really.**  As discussed in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16617/how-to-convince-airport-security-that-i-am-not-dangerous-when-having-metallic-pa?rq=1), implants are *very* common and security is used to dealing with them.  In short:

If it's picked up by the metal detector or full-body scanner, you can tell them what you have and where it is.  They'll use a hand scanner to verify, and you're clear.

If it's not picked up, you have no problem.

Comment: Aye. I'm more worried about any other medical issues I might come across.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much.  Titanium doesn't react with pretty much anything, which is precisely why it's used in medical implants.